# How to do CPanel Backup to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, backup, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am using cPanel for managing my websites in Shared Hosting. Now want to store my backup on my Google Drive. I have check lots of tutorials all are said, we need to do something on WHM. I don't have that. CPanel only i have.

Please help me to store cPanel backup files to Google Drive.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any external plugins or apps to connect cpanel with dropbox or google drive .
as a hosting company we know that few of our clients using  https://backupcp.com for the personal purposes .

Comment: Hi Ebin,

I have check backupcp.com and its shows we need WHM access.I don't have WHM panel, CPanel only i have.

Comment: You can enter cpanel or whm login details.
Both works.
If its cpanel user only 1 cpanel will be shown
If reseller whm user it will show all users under the reseller